# element is not visible on site using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

A chat start button exist in site as shown below
[image]

but while running automated script on puppeteer this button doesn't display. Even i used all kinds waits for it to load. as here below button doesn't appear

[image]

Comment: How is that different from your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64176366/start-chat-doesnt-display-using-puppeteer-but-working-fine-in-by-writing-scri) question?

Comment: @AlonEitan no one commented or answered on previous question and i'm stuck here from 3 days. So I thought maybe someone didn't get it proper in last question. I am stuck here so want help from Professionals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element exist there. Probably UI of button is not appearing because of using delays or not rendering in given time but the element exist there.

Go to inspect and copy the unique identifier of "Start button" from normal browser(which is not running through automated script)

then use `await page.click("button_Identifier");`
and you will see start chat button has clicked and window moved to next step.